# Unique Dynamic Navigation with the Use of Short Tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, function, configuration, navigation

I am trying to figure how to go about adding subpages to this current structure taught to me two years ago. That said, if there is a far better way to create a dynamic navigation, please do inlude some useful documentation and suggestions to study and get up to date.

There's a subpage within the "Design" menu item, but I'm unsure how to go about writing in the $url ending so the menu item will remain highlighted when clicked into:

$nav1['designs.php'] = "Design";

I don't need a drop down of the subpage, however, I do need the "Design" menu item to remain active when clicked into the subpage of "Design".

Though I only need the menu item to remain lit when clicked into current subpages, what would I have to do to create a drop-down menu using this method if I wanted to?

As of now, this is how I've built my top nav inside my config file:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/ Los_Angeles');

define('PAGE_TITLE', basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));

switch (PAGE_TITLE) {

case 'designs.php':

        $title = "Chrysalis Designs";
        $pageID = "Designs";
        $quoteID = "";

        break;

    default:

        $title = PAGE_TITLE;
        $pageID = "";
        $quoteID = "";

}

$nav1['index.php'] = "Samuel Phillps";
$nav1['designs.php'] = "Design";
$nav1['services.php'] = "Services";
$nav1['cases.php'] = "Cases";
$nav1['contactme.php'] = "Contact";

function makeLinks($nav1)

{

    $myReturn = '';

    foreach ($nav1 as $url => $text) {

        if ($url == PAGE_TITLE) {

            $myReturn .= "<li><a class=\"selected\" href=\"$url\">$text</a></li>";
        } else {

            $myReturn .= "<li><a href=\"$url\">$text</a></li>";
        }
    }
    return $myReturn;
}
```

This is how my navigation appears as a short tag in the dynamic header I have created:

```
<nav>

                <ul>

                    <?= makeLinks($nav1) ?>

                    <!-- ORIGINAL HTML MENU ITEM SETUP

                    <li><a href="stp.php">Samuel Phillips</a></li>
                    <li><a href="designs.php">Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="cases.php">Cases</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactme.php">Contact</a></li>
                -->

                </ul>
```

I've tried just adding the url ending that I needed to add the active class to the page, but it failed.

$nav1['designs.php' . 'url.php'] = "Design";

Comment: What sense is `$nav1['designs.php' . 'url.php']` supposed to make? I really very much doubt that the URL of your sub page of design, is actually `designs.phpurl.php` ...?

Comment: url.php is just a placeholder for the actual name of the file in the directory. Replace url.php with cases.php if that makes what I've written clearer. 

I just need the menu item to be connected to the same page as desings.php, or any other menu item that I may choose so that 'Designs' remains active when entering into relative connected pages.

Comment: _"Replace url.php with cases.php if that makes what I've written clearer."_ - then it would be `designs.phpcases.php`, and that would not make much more sense either - I really doubt you have a file named `designs.phpcases.php`?